# Failure to parse json correctly...not sure what the issue is here?

Tags: jquery

I have almost no experience with json and I'm not sure how I'm deviating from the textbook here.  I have a very simple json object that I want to parse.  It is not registering a value for data.user_status.  Where I am going wrong here?

```
$('input#login_submit').click(function(event){
    $.post("/login_ajax/", {post:1,username:$('input#ajax_username').val(), password:$('input[name=password]').val()}, //could also use $(this).serialize() here to capture all form inputs
        function(data){
            if(data.user_status==1){
                 ......(functions happen)

    },'json');
    return false;
    });
```

Firebug shows that I have returned an

Object { user_status=1, user_favorite=1, flag_record=1}

How do I handle this?

Thanks

Comment: do a console.log(data) before the if statement please. but from the looks of it, it should be "1" instead of 1

Comment: Alright I sorted it out by iterating through the data with the $.each method. So then you always have to iterate through the json object, even if it's a list with only a single entry?

Comment: when the value of a property is an integer or float the quotes are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had to iterate over the json object

Answer (score 0):

I dont see where you are telling the $.post that you expect a json object back from the post:

```
(<?php echo json_encode(array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm")); ?>).
$.post("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
  function(data){
    alert(data.name); // John
    alert(data.time); //  2pm
}, "json");
```

The above example is ripped from the jquery docs, but you can see they pass the 'json' datatype as a part of the $.post, and if passed the result will be parsed into a json object on your behalf.